# Bootstrap Modal Window Moves Navigation Bar on Close

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal, navbar

Whenever I open and close a `Bootstrap` `modal window`, my `Bootstrap navbar` shifts over to the side. How do I prevent that from happening, or is it possible to reset the `navbar` back to the correct dimensions once the `modal` has closed?

I have created a **try-it editor** exemplifying the issue [here](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=G4PKPNW4HUAQ). Just open and close the `Modal`, and look at the right side of the `navbar`.

And, if you don't like the **try-it editor**, an `html` example is below:

```js
function openModal() {
        $("#modalPop").modal("show");
    }
```

```css
.tableOne {
        padding: 2px; 
        border: 0px; 
        border-spacing: 0px; 
        border-collapse: collapse; 
        width: 100%; 
        height: 35px; 
        background-color: #0099cc; 
        color: white; 
        font-weight: bold; 
        font-size: 40px; 
        text-indent: 20px;
      }
      .tableTwo {
       padding: 2px;
        border: 0px;
        border-spacing: 0px;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        text-align: right;
        width: 100%;
      }
      .tdOne {
       text-indent: 8px; 
        width: 130px;
      }
      .tdTwo {
        text-indent: 20px;
        padding-bottom: 8px;
        text-align: right;
        color:white; 
        font-weight:bold; 
        font-style: normal; 
        font-size:35%;
      }
      .textOne {
       color: white; 
        font-size: 28px; 
        font-weight: normal;
      }
      .linkOne {
       color:white; 
        text-decoration: none; 
        font-size:12px;
      }
```

```html
<head>
  <title>Side Issue Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body style="padding-top: 200px;">

<nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand navbar-dark" style="background-color: #ff5733; padding:0;">
  
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse flex-column">
            <div style="width:100%;">
                <table class="tableOne">
                    <tr>
                        <td class="tdOne"><span class="textOne"><img src="https://purrli.com/Pix/Logo_white_small.png"></span></td>  
                        <td><span class="textOne"> Side Issue Example</span></td>
                        <td>
                            <table class="tableTwo">
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="tdTwo"><a href="#" class="linkOne">Sign Out</a> &nbsp;</td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>

            </div>

     <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
              <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="firstDrop" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><span style="color:white;">First</span></a>
              <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="firstDrop">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="/One">One</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="/Two">Two</a>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
              <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="secondDrop" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><span style="color:white;">Second</span></a>
              <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="secondDrop">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="/One">One</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="/Two">Two</a>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="/Other"><span style="color:white;">Link</span></a>
            </li>
          </ul>    
    </div>
 
</nav>

<center>
Here is some page content.
<br/><br/>
<a href="#" onclick="javascript:openModal()">Open Modal!</a>
</center>

<div id="modalPop" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" style="overflow-y: initial;">   
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
       <h4 class="modal-title"><span>MODAL</span></h4>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>                
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body" style="max-height: calc(100vh - 200px); overflow-y: auto;">
            This is a modal window.
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>    
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason, when the modal hides, `.navbar` gets new padding values that causes the navbar to shift.

One way to fix it would be to add [`hidden.bs.modal`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/modal/) event listener for when the modal is closed and setting the default padding so it wont shift :

```
<script>
function openModal() {
    $("#modalPop").modal("show");
}

    $(function() { //we have to wait for the DOM to be ready otherwise it won't work
        $('#modalPop').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) { //listen to the modal closed event
            $('nav.navbar').attr('style', 'background-color: #ff5733;padding:0;'); //set the default background-color and padding to prevent the shifting phenomenon 
        })


    });
```

Example below :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Side Issue Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">

  <script>
   function openModal() {
        $("#modalPop").modal("show");
    }
  
  $(function() {
   $('#modalPop').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
    $('nav.navbar').attr('style', 'background-color: #ff5733;padding:0;');
   })
  });  
   </script>
   
   <style>
      .tableOne {
        padding: 2px; 
        border: 0px; 
        border-spacing: 0px; 
        border-collapse: collapse; 
        width: 100%; 
        height: 35px; 
        background-color: #0099cc; 
        color: white; 
        font-weight: bold; 
        font-size: 40px; 
        text-indent: 20px;
      }
      .tableTwo {
       padding: 2px;
        border: 0px;
        border-spacing: 0px;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        text-align: right;
        width: 100%;
      }
      .tdOne {
       text-indent: 8px; 
        width: 130px;
      }
      .tdTwo {
        text-indent: 20px;
        padding-bottom: 8px;
        text-align: right;
        color:white; 
        font-weight:bold; 
        font-style: normal; 
        font-size:35%;
      }
      .textOne {
       color: white; 
        font-size: 28px; 
        font-weight: normal;
      }
      .linkOne {
       color:white; 
        text-decoration: none; 
        font-size:12px;
      }
      
   </style>
</head>
<body style="padding-top: 200px;">

<nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand navbar-dark" style="background-color: #ff5733; padding:0;">
  
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse flex-column">
            <div style="width:100%;">
                <table class="tableOne">
                    <tr>
                        <td class="tdOne"><span class="textOne"><img src="https://purrli.com/Pix/Logo_white_small.png"></span></td>  
                        <td><span class="textOne"> Side Issue Example</span></td>
                        <td>
                            <table class="tableTwo">
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="tdTwo"><a href="#" class="linkOne">Sign Out</a> &nbsp;</td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>

            </div>

     <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
              <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="firstDrop" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><span style="color:white;">First</span></a>
              <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="firstDrop">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="/One">One</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="/Two">Two</a>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
              <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="secondDrop" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><span style="color:white;">Second</span></a>
              <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="secondDrop">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="/One">One</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="/Two">Two</a>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="/Other"><span style="color:white;">Link</span></a>
            </li>
          </ul>    
    </div>
 
</nav>

<center>
Here is some page content.
<br/><br/>
<a href="#" onclick="javascript:openModal()">Open Modal!</a>
</center>

<div id="modalPop" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" style="overflow-y: initial;">   
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
       <h4 class="modal-title"><span>MODAL</span></h4>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>                
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body" style="max-height: calc(100vh - 200px); overflow-y: auto;">
            This is a modal window.
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>    
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you, this is almost exactly what I literally just got working a moment ago. I added the following to my js:
`function fixIt() {$('.navbar').css('padding', 0);};`

And then added a call listening for `hidden.bs.modal` like you said, which called that method:

`$(function(){$( "#modalPop" ).on('hidden.bs.modal', function(){fixIt(); });});`

And that worked! The only other change I had to make was that, because in the real version I make the modals dynamically, I had to add it everywhere I made a new modal.

Comment: You're welcome! If you have to support multiple modals I would suggest you add a specific class to each of your modals (for example : `fixShift`) and then just change the selector to match that class `$('.fixShift')` following the `hidden.bs.modal` event listener so you don't have to make the same event listener for all your modals.

Answer (score 1):

Override the style added with JS in css:

```
body.modal-open {
    padding-right: 0px !important;
}

.navbar {
    padding-right: 16px !important;
}
```

By default when opening modal, Bootstrap hide the scrollbar. This `padding-right` is added to fix move to the right on deletion. If you custom your scrollbar you will change this default behaviour then this bootstrap fix will be transformed by a little mouve to the left.

For people who never seen `!important` in css rules it's important for this override.

Comment: Bootstrap appears to completely overwrite the padding anyway, whether it is !important or not, unfortunately. Hence my other answer, above.

Answer (score 0):

when you open the modal and closes it is setting nav class padding-right to 16px just set to padding:0px !important or padding-right:0px !important is for so bootstrap wont override this style

Comment: can you make this work in the try-it editor that I linked? When I change the top to ``<nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand navbar-dark" style="background-color: #ff5733; padding:0; padding-right:0px !important;">``, it does not appear to make a difference. Bootstrap appears to completely overwrite the padding anyway, whether it is ``!important`` or not.

Answer (score 0):

this works for me, just apply a sticke prop, not fixed

```
header {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
}
```